# Routes navigation is not working in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using router in my NodeJs app.When I am trying to navigate it is unable to navigate to the given page.
Register.js is placed in routes folder and server.js is placed in parent directory.

Here is my code:

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(require('./routes/register'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

app.listen(port, (req,res) => {
  console.log("Server is running at:", +port);
});
```

**Register.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

router.use(bodyParser.json);
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

router.get('/users', (req,res) => {

  console.log('Hello there');

});

module.exports = router;
```

Now when I run this code and go to `localhost:3000/users` nothing happens and not even error shows in console.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in above code.

Comment: one question is your file name `register` or `Register`?

Comment: Its register.js

Comment: Seems like 

`router.use(bodyParser.json);
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));`

is the culprit here.

Comment: @ShobhitChittora is right, should be `router.use(bodyParser.json());` notice the function call

Comment: @Shobhit chittora ,Thanks bro I forgot brackets it should be bodyParser.json()

Answer (score 3):

Use `router.use(bodyParser.json());` in register.js.

Comment: yes bro this was the only mistake in above code.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have used body-parser at wrong place. Also you should initiate those with express instances always.
Also check your file name you have imported. Reigster -> register

Updated code:

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(require('./Register'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, (req,res) => {
    console.log("Server is running at:", +port);
});
```

**Register.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.get('/users', (req,res) => {

    console.log('Hello there');
    res.sendStatus(200)
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: ,bro everything is correct actually problem was in app.use(bodyParser.json) it should be app.use(bodyParser.json()).

Comment: I was talking where you have written body parser on Router call does not make sense since you are trying to parse your every API call.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser